# Feel Confused with usage of pyorient OrientDB/connect/db_open

Tags: python, orientdb, pyorient

## Q1:

I composed a class simplified the usage of OrientDB connection. Partial code like:

```
class DbDelegate(object):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        self._cn = OrientDB(..)
        ...

    def command(self, *args):
        self._cn.db_open(...)
        return self._cn.command(*args)

    def create_db(self): 
        self._cn.connect(self.user_name, self.user_password)
        self._cn.db_create(self.db_name)
        ...
```

The "self._cn.connect" line of create_db function raise exception as:

```
pyorient.exceptions.PyOrientConnectionException: Socket Error [WinError 10038] Socket operation on nonsocket.
```

If the create_db isn't be called at all, the command function called, it runs fine. 
Now these code works,

```
class DbDelegate(object):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        self._cn = OrientDB(..)
        ...

    def command(self, *args):
        self._cn = OrientDB(..)
        self._cn.db_open(...)
        return self._cn.command(*args)

    def create_db(self):
        self._cn = OrientDB(..)
        self._cn.connect(self.user_name, self.user_password)
        self._cn.db_create(self.db_name)
        ...
```

Why is that?

## Q2

According the doc, db_close should be called after db_open call? If call it at the last line of command function, it raise an error.

#### Platform infos:

- OrientDB version: 2.2.20
- pyorient version: 1.5.5
- Python version: 3.6.0
- OS: Windows 10 64x

Answer (score 0):

Turned out it is a small issue. In short, I just called db_close in the wrong place.